# Proving the singleton language {x} is regular for all x ∈ Σ*

Tags: regular-languages, proof-techniques, sets

So I'm aware that the singleton language is in fact regular for all x ∈ Σ*, but I do not understand why it is. A formal proof would help, but also getting some intuition as to why it is regular would also be appreciated! As of now I'm just aware of it as a property, but I don't have a good grasp on why it is regular.

Comment: Any finite language is regular.

Comment: What is your definition of a regular language? If it is a language accepted by a DFA, then you can easily construct a DFA accepting $\{x\}$, which has $|x|+2$ states. It's a good exercise for you.

Comment: If your definition of regularity is based on [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), then this is a very basic fact. Otherwise, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_theorem#Equivalent_formalisms) could be helpful.

Comment: I thought x ∈ Σ* isn't assuming that x is finite? Like, x could be an infinitely large string. So {x} would be a single string with infinite length.

Answer (score 1):

$\Sigma^*$ is a set of finite strings. There are infinitely many of them, but each one is finite – just like there are infinitely many natural numbers but each one of them is finite.

So, for any $x\in\Sigma^*$, $\{x\}$ is a finite language (it contains one string) of finite strings (because everything in $\Sigma^*$ is finite), so it's regular.